# Generic Core Data "Attachable" Parent Class

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

I am working on a Core Data app that has lots of different types of entities.  There is an entity for `Property`, an entity for `Apartment`, an entity for `Tenant`, and some others that I would like to be able to use the iPhone's camera/photo library to attach images to.

I've worked with the camera before in smaller projects, but what I'd like to do this time around is write some generic "Attachable" code and have each of these entities (`Property`, `Apartment`, and `Tenant`) inherit from the `Attachable` class to have all of the necessary code out of the box.

I'm thinking that this will avoid code duplication and be something like [the excellent Ruby/Rails Paperclip plugin](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip).

Before I re-invent the wheel, though, I'd like to know if anything like this is already out there.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to put code that controls the camera or the UI in the managed object subclasses. That would break the Modal-View-Controller design pattern and make the app a tangle. The managed object subclasses should only be concerned with modeling data.

However, there is no reason why you can't have a managed object subclass manage a data file outside of Core Data's persistent store.

In this case, you have to options for storing an image with Core Data. You can simply store the UIImage object directly into a transformable attribute in any entity. However, makes the persistent store huge and can severely slow down fetches. The better method is store the image as a separate file whose pathname is stored in a string attribute.

I suggest creating an `Image` entity and customize its class to managed the file. Use a transient property to represent the actual UIImage object. Then create an abstract parent class for Property, Apartment, and Tenant that has a relationship to the `Image` entity. Property, Apartment, and Tenant will all inherit the `image` relationship.

That way, to set an image for any Property, Apartment, or Tenant you would just use:

```
UIImage *displayImage=aProperty.image.imageObject; //object.relationship.attribute
```

The `Image` object on the other side of the relationship would load and return the UIImage.

You need to handle it this way because of the need to be key-value compliant. This way, anytime you set or remove an image, Core Data updates the object graph to reflect the change.